# Why my code (based on genetic algorithm optimtool) is unable to read a value as input?

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am using the MATLAB optimtool for genetic algorithm optimization.

I am opening a new script with the name 'm_0a4'
`FitnessFunction = @m_0b4;`
`NumberOfVariables = 1;`
`[x,fval] = ga(FitnessFunction, numberOfVariables);%Here I minimize the difference y`

I am opening a second new script naming it 'm_0b4'
`function y = m_0b4(x)`
`prompt = 'write it down';`
`i = input(prompt) %the input value`
`y = x - i; % the variable I want to minimize`

The functionnn m_0b4 request me for a value 'i' and I am typing the input,
The script m_0a4 of genetic algorithm calls the 'y'.

As I type the value, MATLAB keep on requesting me again for a value.
When I am typing 'Enter' MATLAB brings me an error.

*Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than
non-singleton subscripts

Caused by:
    Failure in user-supplied fitness function evaluation.
    GA cannot continue.*

I cant think why MATLAB doesn't understand that I give an input (for example the number 5). Is there any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's pretty weird that your fitness function will request an input from the user. Do you realize that everytime `ga` calls your FitnessFunction it will ask the user for an input?

Comment: Yes, I did realize that but `ga` must call my FitnessFunction one time. By the way I believe, it's weird that my fitness function will be requesting an input from the user many times. I say that because when I simply type for example `i = 1` my `ga` works well and calls the FitnessFunction one time.

Comment: `ga` will work iteratively by calling the fitness function as many times as needed to be within the default tolerance from the minimum (it actually stops when two subsequent calls to the fitness function give the same result). If you define `i=1` you get rid of the problem by not requesting user input. Please have a look at my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Then there isn't any way of user typing the value `i` for all the iterations.

Comment: Well, changing the definition of the function to minimize at each iteration would make no sense at all. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I had to write it in the main script as you suggested. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you should do would be to ask the user for the input *once* before the call to `ga`.

In order for your function `m_0b4` to take this input into account, you can declare `FitnessFunction` as an anonymous function of 1 argument :

**Your new function :**

```
function y = m_0b4(x,i)
y = x - i;
end
```

**In the Main script :**

```
prompt = 'write it down';
i = input(prompt)

% Declare your fitness function that will be executed with the input entered by the user 
FitnessFunction=@(x) m_0b4(x,i);

% Minimize
NumberOfVariables = 1;
[x,fval] = ga(FitnessFunction, NumberOfVariables);
```

### Minor note (Major problem):

The function you're trying to minimize tends to -infinity when x tends to -infinity....

---

### Working example (One that admits a minimum)

```
function y = m_0b4(x,i)
y = abs(x - i);
end
```

**Result :**

With an input `i` set to 20 (And a maximum of 100 generations) :

> x =
>
> 20.012668610027522
>
> fval =
>
> 0.012668610027522

Comment: Why it is necessary to assign and declare my fitness function as anonymous function by the way `FitnessFunction=@(x) m_0b4(x,i); ? `

Comment: It is because you want your fitness function to be depending on only one variable (`x`), and not on the user input `i`. By declaring the function that way, it will always take the same predefined user input `i` and make `x` vary during the process

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say why your code does not work, but here a workaround:

```
function y = m_0b4(x)
i = input('write it down \n')
y = x - i;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We encounter the same problem.When I am writing on your way,  I am facing the same symptoms.